# to get alert if any micro-service is down

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

In microservices how to get an alert if any microservice is down??

I am using Spring boot for the creation of microservices, I want to have an alert mechanism if any service is down. For example:- I am having 4 microservices(s1,s2,s3,s4), s1 communicating with s2 and s2 with s3 and s3 with s4, if s3 is down how can I get an alert that s3 is down?

are there any tools that can give alerts when the service is down?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want a monitor for Micro services, you can use multiple ways

the popular option for the spring boot application is using eureka discovery

[Article from baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka)

i would like to add should enable the health check as well
[spring doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/2.0.x/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html#_eureka_s_health_checks)

Comment: by using eureka we can register the service and get to know which services are up at that point, but this requires manual checking with eureka client, can I know if there is a way that can trigger a mail or something when the service is down?

Comment: there is no hook calls from Eureka, however you can enable the health endpoint and ping in some intervals for status checking if anything went wrong you can fire an email api.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I think that would work, enable actuator health check and trigger it with spring starter mail if the status is not "up"

Comment: Or could you consider to use K8s? that will restart the server automatically.

Comment: I am new to these concepts, will make a note of K8s